# Autosys - Release Job Dependency

Tags: autosys

I'm looking for a solution for the below scenario. I'm not sure if it's even possible or not.

I've been working on CA Workload automation D series now, there is a release dependency option available in that tool, but when I try to relate the same with Autosys, I'm not able to find a solution.

So please check and help me with this.

Lets say there are 3 jobs in a box A,B,C

- A
- B runs on Success of A
- C runs on Success of B.

> A is in RU state.
> B is Active & waiting for SUCCESS(A),
> C is Active and waiting for SUCCESS(B).

Now is there any way we can let the job C start executing? (only for this run)

We still want B to execute, but for now we don't want C to wait for SUCCESS of B.

Comment: Why not update Job C as SUCCESS (A) then, if it has no dependency on Job B.

Comment: Or just keep no condition, when the box is activated job A and C would start simultaneously

Comment: Thank you for the response @Piyush, But as I said, that requirement is only for that particular run. I don't want to change the dependencies. 

We are talking about only for one particular one, only once.

Comment: if it's a onetime case, "Force Start" the job C. I am still not convinced if this is a one time scene than why are you looking to have some  kind of configurations changes to be made ?